# Как сделать такой эффект со скроллом?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-sdk

[image: макет]
У меня есть ScrollView, у которого height и width установлены match_parent. У этого ScrollView есть RelativeLayout с контентом. Когда пользователь скроллит экран, этот RelativeLayout покрывает верхнюю часть экрана. Но проблема заключается в том, что в этой верхней части экрана помимо разных вьюшек располагается кнопка close который должна нажиматься когда она видна, когда же нижний RelativeLayout покрывает её она должна переставать нажиматься. Проблема заключается в том, что ScrollView не даёт нажаться этой самой кнопке. Если по иерархии XML расположить кнопку в ScrollView, то она тоже будет скроллиться, а мне необходимо, чтобы верхние вьюшки и эта кнопка оставались статичными.

```
<carbon.widget.RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cyan"
    tools:context=".OptionsActivity">

    <carbon.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        app:carbon_elevation="0dp" />

    <com.xw.repo.widget.BounceScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- content -->

        </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

    </com.xw.repo.widget.BounceScrollView>

</carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Разметку покажите свою

Comment: @ArtyMorris добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользовался `NestedScrollView` вместе с `CollapsingToolbarLayout`